# konva js make an object not draggable

Tags: function, html5-canvas, konvajs

I need to create a function that changes the attribe of an object (circle) from draggable to not draggable.
As well it would be ideal to use a mouse action, but the mouse is used for dragging the object, so it might need to be clicked with the mouse to make it active followed by a button to change the attribute.

This is the code that I used to create the circle, and the new function needs to change the attribute draggable.

```
function addCircle(){
        var circle = new Konva.Circle({
          x: stage.width() / 2,
          y: stage.height() / 2,
          radius: 70,
          fill: 'red',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 4,
          draggable: true,
          id: [ident],
          name: 'test',
        });
      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(circle);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
    };
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome Walter. The shape property draggable(bool) controls whether or not the shape is draggable. To turn dragging off use shape.draggable(false), or use true to enable dragging when it was previously disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use mouse action to toggle `draggable` value you can do this:

```js
circle.on('click tap', () => {
  circle.draggable(!circle.draggable());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lavrton, thank you for your input...
I've tried adding the code you recommended, and I'm geting the following error

(index):35 Uncaught ReferenceError: circle is not defined.

My circle function is in "konva_library.js", so I'm thinking the problem is that the event is looking for a circle that hasen't been defined yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Konvajs</title>
        <script src='konva_library.js'></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/7.0.0/konva.min.js"></script>

        </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <button onclick="addCircle()">Add Circle</button>
                <div id='container'></div>
        </div>

        <script>

            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            var stage = new Konva.Stage({
                container: 'container',
                width: width,
                height: height
            });

            var layer = new Konva.Layer();
            stage.add(layer);

            // (index):35 Uncaught ReferenceError: circle is not defined

            circle.on('dblclick', () => {
                circle.draggable(!circle.draggable());
            });

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are quire right, since your circle is added on click of the add circle button, then this circle click event cannot be bound to the as-yet non-existent circle ! This is a generic JS issue and not specifically related to Konva. To set listeners on future objects is called  'delegation', and you set the listener on a parent object. Konva has a demo for this in the tutorials, but it uses a single shape so I made a modified version [here](https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/PoZQgRJ). Note this creates the shapes prior to the listener, but it is still a demo of delegation.